# Powering 800W Nichrome coil with 220V AC

Tags: power-supply, power, heat, dimmer

I have bought an 800W coiled nichrome wire from a store (it's the smallest rating they have). I am planning to use it on my automated egg incubator as a heating element and I am wondering if I can power it up with 220V AC. I have tried using 2 100W light bulbs as heating element for the incubator but the settling time before it gets hot is too long (around 20 mins) so I have decided to use nichrome wire instead. I will also use an AC dimmer circuit to control the temperature inside. Will it be possible for me to power the nichrome coil by 220 V AC? and can the nichrome coil withstand constant dimming changes? thank you!

Comment: Didn't you ask at the store..?

Comment: Table 3 at Wikipedia may help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome

Comment: At what voltage will the nichrome wire consume 800 watts?  You have a very different problem if it consumes 800 watts at 12 volts vs 800 watts at 220 volts.

Comment: I wish to power it with 220V AC if possible, @PeterBennett

Comment: Hi @WesleyLee , I asked but they also don't know how (I know, it's frustrating)

Comment: What cold resistance do you get on the nicrome (spool)?

Comment: around 35-40ohms @winny

Comment: Nichrome don't change it's resistance very much so you can approximate it to 1.3 kW. Feel free to dim it.

Comment: See this table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome#Table_3:_Cold_resistance_.28.CE.A9_at_75.C2.B0F.29_and_wire_gauge_vs._power_output_.28W.29_at_operating_voltage_.28V.29. where it seems that a cold resistance 35-40 ohms doesn't seem to fit an 800 W spec. More like a 350 W, if 120 VAC RMS.

Comment: Consider getting a cheap PID controller to operate it, rather than a dimmer, at some point. The dimmer is open loop. The PID will close the loop with temperature measurement and will probably work better for your needs. I set up one of these for a commercial hatchery, years back. Very happy results.

Comment: I am using arduino as the controlling unit of all parameters of the incubator @jonk

Comment: @jonk, the OP said 220V.

Comment: @JohnBryanInfantado Got it. I was imagining a light dimmer being used, I guess. My mistake.

Comment: @mkeith I saw the 220VAC, but I didn't see the OP say that the seller said the 800 W was for 220 VAC. Different things. But I might just be picky about such things. Regardless, it doesn't work for 800 W at 220 VAC, either. Like winny said, it's more like 1.3 kW. The numbers just don't jive. That's all.

Comment: @JohnBryanInfantado Controlled via relay or controlled triac?

Comment: it's ok @jonk I appreciate the help.

Comment: controlled via an AC PWM dimmer for arduino @winny

Comment: @JohnBryanInfantado Ok, then you have all options available for PID or hysteresis control from the temperature sensor.

Comment: @jonk, agree. My take is that the element is rated for 800 W, period. Up to the user to avoid supplying too much power. I just meant that winny was probably using 220, not 120.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, he says as much, saying he wants to use 220 VAC. I'm assuming this is Europe and not US split-phase. It's really not a tough problem. Very tolerant to PWM, nothing much really to worry over. I think it's just going to work well. PID tuning may be a problem with delays, but he's hoping for faster response times and that ONLY makes PID work better, not worse. So it's goodness all around, I think.

Answer (score 2):

> I have bought an 800W coiled nichrome wire from a store (it's the smallest rating they have). I am planning to use it on my automated egg incubator as a heating element and I am wondering if I can power it up with 220V AC.

Nichrome wire by itself does not have a wattage rating.
A coil of given resistance will dissipate a reasonably constant amount of heat power across its expected temperature range.

Power = V^2/R or
R = V^2/Power.
IF your coiled wire is intended as a 220 VAC & 800 Watt heating element it will have a resistance of about R = V^2/Power = 220^2/800 = 60.5 Ohms (ie ~= 60 Ohms.)
If it is rated for use at some other voltage (DC or RMS AC) then it will have some other resistance to give rated power at rated voltage.
eg a 110 VAC 800 Watt element will have a resistance of V^2/Power = 110^2/800 ~= 15 Ohms

> I have tried using 2 100W light bulbs as heating element for the incubator but the settling time before it gets hot is too long (around 20 mins) so I have decided to use nichrome wire instead.

At most the element has 4 x the lightbulb  power so ~~~ 1/4 the settling time.

> I will also use an AC dimmer circuit to control the temperature inside. Will it be possible for me to power the nichrome coil by 220 V AC?

If rated for 220 VAC it will work on 220 VAC.

If rated for > 220 VAC it will be OK with 220 VAC 
(eg if rated at 800W @ 230 VAC  it will produce 800W x (220/230)^2 =~ 730 Watt. Resistance and voltage tolerances are probably such that the difference is insignificant).

If rated for < 220 VAC it will work on no more than rated voltage and the dimmer must not allow more than 800 Watt continuous heating.

If say rated for 100 V operation and used with a dimmer then an about 2kW dimmer may be needed as Imax at full power at 110 VAC is double I max at 220 VAC and the same power.

> ... and can the nichrome coil withstand constant dimming changes? thank you!

Yes.
After very long use Nichrome forms a visible oxide layer but this is thin and tightly bound.

---

Added 2017:

User said resistance is about 35 to 40 Ohms.
For 800W V = (P x R)^0.5 = (800 x 35-to-40)^0.5 = 167 to 180 Volts
ie not 800W at any normal mains voltage.

At 230 VAC P = V^2/R =~ 1300W
At 110 VAC P ~= 300 Watt

[**The OP**](https://www.facebook.com/jbinfantado)  is located in the Philippines  where mains voltage is 220 V (@ 60 Hz).
To provide 800W the resistance = V^2/P =~ 60 Ohms.

SO the figures do not "add up" BUT the above notes and calculations would allow a useful answer to be obtained.

Comment: Typo: "If rated for < 220 VAC it will be OK with 220 VAC."

Comment: @OskarSkog Thanks. Corrected and answer update. FYI OP - who has mot come back - is https://www.facebook.com/jbinfantado